# FragmentTabHost passing View components from Fragment to another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like to separate the form into 2 tabs, the second tab includes
 a confirmation bottom which should check if the required fields are
 filled up and continue submit it to the server.

Some of the required fields are in fragment 1(tab 1), and my button
 onclick function is on fragment 2(tab2).

How can I pass the EditText view components from fragment 1 xml to
 fragment 2 java class.

Or should I put all of the functions inside Main Activity?

**Main Activity**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.create_company);

     final FragmentTabHost tabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
     tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
     //1
     tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Basic Information")
                     .setIndicator("Basic Information"),
             BasicCompanyInformation.class,
             null);
     //2
     tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Contact")
                     .setIndicator("Contact"),
             ContactCompany.class,
             null);
 }
 //Fragment 1
 public class ContactCompany extends Fragment {

 Button btnSubmit;
 EditText companyName;

 @Override
 public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
     super.onAttach(activity);

     CreateCompanyActivity createCompanyActivity = (CreateCompanyActivity) activity;
 }

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View basicCompanyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.basic_company_information, container,
false);
     companyName = (EditText) basicCompanyView.findViewById(R.id.edtTxtCompName);
     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_company, container, false);
 }

 @Override
 public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
 }

 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     btnSubmit = (Button) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
     btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             String companyNameValue = companyName.getText().toString();
             btnSubmit.setText(companyNameValue);
         }
     });
 }

 }
 //Fragment 2
 public class BasicCompanyInformation extends Fragment {

 private String[] statusArray;
 private Spinner statusSpinner;
 private Button btnNext1;
 @Override
 public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
     super.onAttach(activity);

     CreateCompanyActivity createCompanyActivity = (CreateCompanyActivity) activity;
 }

 @Override
 public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
     statusArray = new String[] {
             "Call", "Following", "Deal", "Give up"
     };
 }

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.basic_company_information, container, false);
 }
 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     statusSpinner = (Spinner)getView().findViewById(R.id.statusSpinner);
     btnNext1 = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.btnNext1);

     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
             R.layout.drop_down, statusArray);
     statusSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
     btnNext1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
             tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
         }
     });
 }
 }
```

**Fragment1 xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#f4f4f4">
 <ScrollView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <TableLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:background="#fff"
         android:stretchColumns="*">

         <TableRow
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/border">

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                 android:text="Name:"
                 android:id="@+id/txtCompName"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"/>

             <EditText
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:id="@+id/edtTxtCompName"
                 android:hint="Company Name"
                 android:background="@drawable/border"
                 android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                 android:singleLine="true"
                 android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                 />
         </TableRow>

         <TableRow
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/border">

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                 android:text="Status:"
                 android:id="@+id/txtStatus"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"/>

             <Spinner
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="40dp"
                 android:id="@+id/statusSpinner"
                 android:layout_column="1"
                 android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />


         </TableRow>

         <TableRow
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/border">

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                 android:text="Reg No:"
                 android:id="@+id/txtRegNo"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"/>

             <EditText
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:id="@+id/edtTxtRegNo"
                 android:hint="Register No."
                 android:background="@drawable/border"
                 android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                 android:singleLine="true"
                 android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"/>
         </TableRow>

         <TableRow
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/border">

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                 android:text="Type:"
                 android:id="@+id/txtBusinessType"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"/>

             <EditText
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:id="@+id/edttxtBusinessType"
                 android:hint="Business Type"
                 android:background="@drawable/border"
                 android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                 android:singleLine="true"
                 android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"/>
         </TableRow>

         <TableRow
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/border">

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                 android:text="Address:"
                 android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:layout_gravity="center|top"/>

            <EditText
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                 android:gravity="top"
                 android:lines="5"
                 android:ems="10"
                 android:scrollbars="vertical"
                 android:id="@+id/edtTxtAddress"
                 android:hint="Address"
                 android:background="@drawable/border"
                 android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                 android:maxLines="5"/>
         </TableRow>

         <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
             <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Next"
                 android:id="@+id/btnNext1"
                 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

         </RelativeLayout>
     </TableLayout>
 </ScrollView>> </LinearLayout>
```

**Fragment 2 xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <ScrollView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <TableLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:background="#fff"
         android:stretchColumns="*">

         <TableRow
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/border">

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                 android:text="Person:"
                 android:id="@+id/txtPerson"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"/>

             <EditText
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:id="@+id/editTxtPerson"
                 android:hint="Person in charge"
                 android:background="@drawable/border"
                 android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                 android:singleLine="true"
                 android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                 />
         </TableRow>

         <TableRow
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/border">

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                 android:text="E-mail:"
                 android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"/>

             <EditText
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:id="@+id/editTxtEmail"
                 android:hint="E-mail address"
                 android:background="@drawable/border"
                 android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                 android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                 android:singleLine="true"/>
         </TableRow>

         <TableRow
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/border">

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                 android:text="Tel:"
                 android:id="@+id/txtTel"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"/>

             <EditText
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:id="@+id/edtTxtTel"
                 android:hint="Telephone"
                 android:background="@drawable/border"
                 android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                 android:singleLine="true"
                 android:inputType="phone"/>
         </TableRow>

         <TableRow
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/border">

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                 android:text="Remark"
                 android:id="@+id/txtRemark"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:layout_gravity="center|top"/>

             <EditText
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                 android:gravity="top"
                 android:lines="5"
                 android:ems="10"
                 android:scrollbars="vertical"
                 android:id="@+id/edtTxtRemark"
                 android:hint="Remark"
                 android:background="@drawable/border"
                 android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                 android:maxLines="5"/>
         </TableRow>

         <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
             <Button
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Confirm"
                 android:id="@+id/btnSave"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

         </RelativeLayout>
     </TableLayout>
 </ScrollView>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main fragment(the one holding view pager, tab layout) keep the references of the two fragments(u want only the fisrt, but in case later u may also need second). like this:

```
private SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Log.d("dj", "intializing items FragPageAdapter");
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        Log.d("dj", "destroyed items FragPageAdapter");
        registeredFragments.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int fragmentPosition) {

    return registeredFragments.get(fragmentPosition);
    }
```

And in your fragment 2 where u want to reference it and check some results do this: 
make sure u have set a tag for the main fragment when your doing the transaction in the ur activity holding the mainfragment. so that u can use the tag to reference the main fragment.

```
mainFragment= (MainFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().
            findFragmentByTag(ActivityHoldingMainFragment.TAG_FOR_MAIN_FRAG);
```

In the second fragment get the reference of the first fragment like this:

```
public Fragment findFragmentByPosition(int fragmentPosition) {

    return mainFragment.getRegisteredFragment(fragmentPosition);
}
FirstFragment firstFrag = (FirstFragment ) findFragmentByPosition(0);
ArrayList<String> formOneData = firstFrag.getFormOneData();
```

//findFragmentByPosition(0) will be holding first fragment;

In the first fragment create a method to fetch all data; like this:

```
public ArrayList<String> getFormOneData(){
    //TODO perform fecthing data from edit texts here and pass it as an //arraylist or any other of your choice
}
```

Comment: Btw, how can i get my fragment tag in another activity?

Comment: make a static variable in the activity class where your using it and then u can use it. like this.... In the activity where u do transaction : - ** Declare a class level variable :public static final String TAG_FOR_MAIN_FRAG = "packageName.MainFragment";
Then declare and initialize ur main fragment: MainFragment mainFrag = new MainFragment();//later do the transaction
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(container.getId(), mainFrag, TAG_FOR_MAIN_FRAG).addToBackStack(TAG_FOR_MAIN_FRAG).commit(); ** // adding to the backstack is ur option. u can remove it also

Comment: Then in another activity to reference ur mainFragment use the tag declared as public static in previously mentioned activity.